# interchange boundary with image of holomoprhic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:D\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be an holomorphic non costant function;

there are some conditions on $f$ or on the domain $D\subset \mathbb{C}$ in such a way that $f(\partial D)=\partial f(D)$ ?

Thank's for your answers or for possibile references.

P.S. I know that if $D$ is bounded and $f$ extend continuously on $\bar{D}$ and $f$ is bijective or proper then $f(\partial D)=\partial f(D)$.

But there are some other hypothesis for ensure this?

In particular: if $h$ is a Mobius transformation, then $h(\partial \mathbb{H})=\partial h(\mathbb{H})$ ?

(where $\mathbb{H}$ is the upper half plane as usual).

Comment: Well $D$ has to be a closed set right? $\partial D\subseteq D$ for $f$ to be defined on it?

Comment: I'm sorry, but i've implicitely supposed that f extends continuously on $\bar{D}$. Anyway looks to the P.S. that i've edited.

Comment: So for your edit about mobius transformations, you're asking what happens to the real line? Mobius transformations take circ-lines to circ-lines, when thought of as maps on the riemann sphere. So a line such as the real line gets mapped to a circle or a line depending on the mobius transformation in question. Since the image is a closed set, $h(\partial \Bbb H)=\partial h(\Bbb{H})$?

Comment: For example $\partial S^1=S^1$ as a set in $\Bbb C$ with the usual topology.